# Sylius 1.3 - class "App\Entity\X" sub class of "Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\X" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, sylius, sylius-1.3

**Contents of /config/packages/_sylius.yaml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@SyliusCoreBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml" }

    - { resource: "@SyliusAdminBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml" }
    - { resource: "@SyliusAdminApiBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml" }

    - { resource: "@SyliusShopBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml" }

parameters:
    sylius_core.public_dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/public'

sylius_shop:
    product_grid:
        include_all_descendants: true

sylius_theme:
    sources:
        filesystem:
            directories:
                - "%kernel.project_dir%/themes"

sylius_addressing:
    resources:
        country:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Country
```

**Contents of /src/Entity/Country.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country as BaseCountry;

class Country extends BaseCountry
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $flag;

    /**
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function getFlag(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->flag;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $flag
     */
    public function setFlag(bool $flag): void
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;
    }
}
```

**Contents of /src/Resources/config/doctrine/Country.orm.yml**

```
App\Entity\Country:
  type: entity
  table: sylius_country
  fields:
    flag:
      type: boolean
      nullable: true
```

Upon running Symfony's schema update command, however, the following error message is displayed:

***Class "App\Entity\Country" sub class of "Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.***

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mapping your entity like this.

# config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            AppEntity:
                type: xml
                is_bundle: false
                prefix: App\Entity
                dir: '%project.dir%/src/Resources/config/doctrine/model'
```

and then create your mapping file eg. `src/Resources/config/doctrine/model/YourEntity.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! To anyone looking for a solution for the above issue, it is crucial to point out that if you have a YML mappings file, change the "type" attribute to "yml".